# Why does pandas.to_numeric result in a list of lists?

Tags: python, pandas

I am trying to import csv data into a pandas dataframe. To do this I am doing the following:

```
df = pd.read_csv(StringIO(contents), skiprows=4, delim_whitespace=True,index_col=False,header=None)
index = pd.MultiIndex.from_arrays((columns,  units, descr))
df.columns = index
df.columns.names = ['Name','Unit','Description']
df = df.apply(pd.to_numeric)
data['isotherm'] = df
```

This produces e.g. the following table:

```
In: data['isotherm']
Out:
Name             Relative_Pressure  Volume_STP
Unit                             -       ccm/g
Description                   p/p0  
0                         0.042691     29.3601
1                         0.078319     30.3071
2                         0.129529     31.1643
3                         0.183355     31.8513
4                         0.233435     32.3972
5                         0.280847     32.8724
```

However if I only want to get the values of the column `Relative_Pressure` I get this output:

```
In: data['isotherm']['Relative_Pressure'].values
Out:
array([[0.042691],
       [0.078319],
       [0.129529],
       [0.183355],
       [0.233435],
       [0.280847]])
```

Of course I could now for every column I want to use flatten

```
x = [item for sublist in data['isotherm']['Relative_Pressure'].values for item in sublist]
```

However this would lead to a lot of extra effort and would also reduce the readability. How can I for the whole data frame make sure the data is flat?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

`array([[...]])` is not a list of lists, but a 2D numpy array. (I'm not sure why the values are returned as a single-column 2D array rather than a 1D array here, though. When I create a primitive DataFrame, a single column's values are returned as a 1D array.)

You can concatenate and flatten them using numpy's built-in functions, eg.

```
x = data['isotherm']['Relative_Pressure'].flatten()
```

Edit: This might be caused by the MultiIndex.

Comment: In my case it would need `data['isotherm']['Relative_Pressure'].values.flatten()`. There is no possibility to flatten all rows of the data frame so that later on only `data['isotherm']['Relative_Pressure'].values` would be necessary?

Comment: Good answer! As your edit suspects, the reason why `.values` gives a 2D array in this case is because the columns of the DataFrame are a MultiIndex. In this case, since there's a one-to-one correspondence between the labels in the column levels, it might be worth flattening the columns into a one-level index with this idiom: `df.columns = ['_'.join(colname) for colname in df.columns.values]` (which will give rather garbled column names in this case).

Answer (score 0):

The direct way of indexing into one column belonging to your `MultiIndex` object is with a `tuple` as follows:

```
data[('isotherm', 'Relative_Pressure')]
```

which will return a `Series` object whose `.values` attribute will give you the expected 1D array.  The docs discuss this [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/advanced.html#advanced-indexing-with-hierarchical-index)

You should be careful using chained indexing like `data['isotherm']['Relative_Pressure']` because you won't know if you are dealing with a copy of the data or a view of the data.  Please do a SO search of pandas' `SettingWithCopyWarning` for more details or read the docs [here](http://pandas.pydata.org/pandas-docs/stable/user_guide/indexing.html#why-does-assignment-fail-when-using-chained-indexing).